# Create a convex country flag with glossy effect wrapping an uneven rounded border div using CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: worldCup]

I'm trying to create a World Cup 2018 page using the design that was used in the world cup 2018 qualification european zone (using the image that i've attached).

Please correct me if i'm wrong for some of these points:

1. In the **EUROPEAN ZONE** title, i can achieve this with a trapezoid rounded border.
2. For the title banner, it is using an uneven border `div`. This will have the same `div` alongside with the country names. I've tried using `border-radius` with the `/` operator maybe there is a better solution (if there is).
   And also if you can see there is a small lens flare (not sure if that is the correct term) on top of the `div`.
3. For all the banner `div` i can put some gradient background color to make it look it has a 3D effect and add some glossy effect.
4. For the dark transparent background i can do it the same with `border-radius`. maybe with some concave `border` using the `:after` selector.

This part is where i'm stuck: I'm not sure how to recreate the country flags that has a convex shape but it looks like wrapping the div (maybe add a box-shadow effect) and add a glossy effect.

I'm assuming I can achieve this with CSS only, or maybe a little bit of Javascript. But no jQuery because I'm planning to create this in react.

Here's what I've got so far:

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 40px 40px / 40px 40px 90px 90px;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

#flag {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 40px 40px / 40px 40px 90px 90px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

#flag:after {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  left: 44px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 40px 40px / 40px 40px 90px 90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="flag"></div>
  <div id="team">Country Name</div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praburangki/ph90dfdh/)

Comment: Using `box-shadow` sounds like a decent idea. Did you have any luck trying that?

Comment: You might try using vectors.. maybe some [SVG files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) would help facilitate those shapes.

Comment: border radii and shadows won't help you distort the flag image - I'm assuming the flags themselves are some sort of image?